# Can we predict sales using time series or Regression

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, regression, forecasting

**Input**: I have a dataset that has sale from the last three years and does not have any missing information along with some other features like Date, Promotion, Store_number, Public_holiday_indicator, Promotion_running, weather etc. The dataset ranges from 1st Jan 2017 to 1st Jan 2020

**Output** : What I want to predict is, sales for the next two month i.e. 2nd Jan to 2nd March 2020

My question is that is this a regression problem as I have got other features that impacts the sales or is this a time series problem as I have got a time bound data and there are no missing values in the Date column. Or Can I solve this using both the approaches and choose the one which has better results?

Comment: Thats a big question btw the problem is that your data is not independent so a regression model could be risky..

Answer (score 0):

If you have information about the other named features for the next two months, so you can actually use that information to predict the sales.

Regression and Time-series problems are not completely independent. In fact, most of the methods are based on learning the relationships between the relevant predictors and predicting a future response. ([Autoregressive Dynamics](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiqu8-cxYnuAhXgxjgGHY86AWcQFjACegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathworks.com%2Fdiscovery%2Ftime-series-regression.html&usg=AOvVaw2AhGG3WV9747mGK01V-HVL)).
You will be using some regression methods in time series forecasting too.

You can start by understanding what types of data would be available for the next few months while making a prediction, and then only use those features to train models. You can start with autoregressive models, and proceed to more complicated ones.

Answer (score 0):

As you have some predictors for the sales variable, I would suggest you to analyze the correlation between different variables and sales. Use those variables as predictors while fitting regression model those have a better correlation. Also, try fitting autoregressive models available for time series analysis. Then you can choose the best model to forecast by accuracy measures and just go with that one.